# Can I do this in .Net and WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vba, vb6

We have a third party app that has VBA integrated into it. This all allow us to open a vb6 ActiveX DLL that contains a UI and we pass the apps instance to the vb6 DLL.

```vb
' Instantiate the SMTree UI.
Set oSMTree = CreateObject("SMTree.clsMain")
    
' Start it up.
oSMTree.cMain Application
```

Then in the VB6 app the main looks like:

```vb
Public Sub Main(app As ACNProfessionalAB.CMerchman)

    Set oACNApplication = app

End Sub
```

Is there a way to create a WPF app that can be called in the same way and pass in the callings app instance so I don't have to continue using VB6?

Thanks in advance!
rich

Answer (score 1):

If you can create the object via a COM Interop in .Net you should then be able to assign a reference to that object as the interface will be the same.

Just add the ActiveX dll as a reference via the project references screen which will generate the interop dll and then use your exisiting code as above to assign the reference in your xaml.vb file.